# How can Convert traditional ADO.Net search to Linq Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

first, sorry my bad English.
in the traditional ADO.Net I used this function for search and got DataTable of rows to show in GridView or ...

```
public DataTable GetTableData(string fieldName, string value)
{
    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ResearchPackDB;Integrated Security=True;");
    scon.Open();
    string str = string.Format("SELECT * FROM V_ScientificNews WHERE {0} LIKE {1}", fieldName, value);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(str, scon);
    sda.Fill(ds);
    scon.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

Now I want rewrite this function with Linq Entity, function like this!!

```
    public List<V_ScientificNews> GetNews(string fieldName, string value)
{
    var q = (from r in _entities.V_ScientificNews
                select r)
        .Where(?????????????);
    return q.ToList();
}
```

if have any Idea please tell me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the following one:

```
public List<V_ScientificNews> GetNewsByFieldName(string value)
{
    var q = (from r in _entities.V_ScientificNews
             where r.FieldName.Contains(value)   
             select r);

    return q.ToList();
}
```

or this one:

```
public List<V_ScientificNews> GetNewsByFieldName(string value)
{
    var q = _entities.V_ScientificNews.Where(x=>x.FieldName.Contains(value));
    return q.ToList();
}
```

So for instance, if you want to get the scientific news, whose property called `Name` contains the `value`, then you could declare a method like the below:

```
public List<V_ScientificNews> GetNewsByName(string value)
{
    var q = (from r in _entities.V_ScientificNews
             where r.Name.Contains(value)   
             select r);

    return q.ToList();
}
```